# Must issue a STARTTLS command first. mail.smtp.EnableSSL.enable already set to true

Tags: java, spring, maven, email, starttls

I am working on Java Spring, Maven and I am trying to send a mail on gmail, using a gmail id. I am getting this error:

```
com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSendFailedException: 530 5.7.0 Must issue a STARTTLS command first. 11sm885884pfp.38 - gsmtp
```

even through I have set the parameter

```
mail.smtp.starttls.enable
```

to true.

This is my function:

```
public String sendMail(String to, String subject, String textMessage) throws IOException {
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put("mail.transport.protocol", "smtp");
    props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
    props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
    Session mailSession = Session.getInstance(props);
    mailSession.setDebug(true);
    Message simpleMessage = new MimeMessage(mailSession);

    InternetAddress fromAddress = from@gmail.com;
    InternetAddress toAddress = null;
    try {
        toAddress = new InternetAddress(to);
    } catch (AddressException e) {
        System.out.print("\nError in Address of Sender or reciever\n");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        simpleMessage.setFrom(fromAddress);
        simpleMessage.setRecipient(RecipientType.TO, toAddress);
        simpleMessage.setSubject(subject);
        simpleMessage.setText(textMessage);
        SMTPTransport t = (SMTPTransport) mailSession.getTransport("smtp");
        t.setStartTLS(true);
        t.connect("smtp.gmail.com", "from@gmail.com", "from.password!");
        t.sendMessage(simpleMessage, simpleMessage.getAllRecipients());
        t.close();

    } catch (MessagingException e) {             
        System.out.print("\nError in message Genration\n");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return "success";
}
```

All the answers on SO tell us to set mail.smtp.starttls.enable to true. Doing that even does not work.

I have also included the javax.mail dependency in my pom as:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
    <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
    <version>1.4</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you're using spring, it's better to incorporate their abstractions instead of `javax.mail` low level API. In fact, you can use `JavaMailSender` and its implementation, `JavaMailSenderImpl`, to achieve the same result. See [this](http://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-sending-e-mail-via-gmail-smtp-server-with-mailsender/) for an example.